# Change em-dash character in an OpenType font with xetex

Tags: fonts, xetex, symbols, ligatures

In a (OTF) font I'm using with `xetex`, loaded with the `mapping=tex-text` option, I found that the em-dash character is too thin, so I would like to replace it with a heavier one.  For example, suppose I want to replace it with an `\hrule` (or, equivalently, a `\vrule`).  What should I do?  How are characters mapped to ligature combinations?

Comment: Which opentype font do you use -- some have more than one glyph to represent an em-dash. Separately, are you constrained to use XeTeX, or might a Lua(La)TeX-based solution be of interest to you?

Comment: Even if that sounds patronizing: Don't! If it is a well designed font, there is usually a good reason for things to look like they do. If it isn't well designed and you still think it looks bad: Could you use another font?

Comment: If you have to: Modifying the font itself is probably the easiest. Alternatively: Just search-replace the `---` in the tex-file by a convenient macro.

Comment: @Mico. I am using Monotype Baskerville.  How can I check if there are other em-dash symbols in the font? And, eventually, how can I use them?  I am constrained to use xetex, but a luatex solution could be of interest to someone else or as a future reference for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XeTeX can use the powerful method of mapping files.

Locate on your TeX system the file `tex-text.map` and copy it into the working directory as `baskerville-dash.map`.

Open the file with a text editor and modify it to look like

```
; TECkit mapping for TeX input conventions <-> Unicode characters

LHSName "baskerville-dash"
RHSName "UNICODE"

pass(Unicode)

; ligatures from Knuth's original CMR fonts
U+002D U+002D           <>      U+2013  ; -- -> en dash
U+002D U+002D U+002D    <>      U+2015  ; --- -> horizontal bar (was U+2014)
U+2014                  <>      U+2015  ; em dash -> horizontal bar

U+0027                  <>      U+2019  ; ' -> right single quote
U+0027 U+0027           <>      U+201D  ; '' -> right double quote
U+0022                   >      U+201D  ; " -> right double quote

U+0060                  <>      U+2018  ; ` -> left single quote
U+0060 U+0060           <>      U+201C  ; `` -> left double quote

U+0021 U+0060           <>      U+00A1  ; !` -> inverted exclam
U+003F U+0060           <>      U+00BF  ; ?` -> inverted question

; additions supported in T1 encoding
U+002C U+002C           <>      U+201E  ; ,, -> DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK
U+003C U+003C           <>      U+00AB  ; << -> LEFT POINTING GUILLEMET
U+003E U+003E           <>      U+00BB  ; >> -> RIGHT POINTING GUILLEMET
```

Save the file and run

```
teckit_compile baskerville-dash
```

that should produce a file `baskerfille-dash.tec`.

Now test the new mapping file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Mapping=baskerville-dash]{Baskerville}

\begin{document}

a---b—c

\end{document}
```

Between `b` and `c` in the input file there's U+2014 (em dash).

[image]

Here's the output with the default `tex-text` mapping

[image]

Now keep the `baskerville-dash` file along with the TeX source, or place it in some place that XeTeX will look in for files, presumably

```
mkdir -p $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME)/fonts/misc/xetex/fontmapping/baskerville-dash
mv baskerville-dash.* $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME)/fonts/misc/xetex/fontmapping/baskerville-dash
```

or a similar trick for other operating systems.

Run XeLaTeX on the test file again for being sure all went well.

Comment: How can other ligatures like `ff`, `fi`, `ffl` be typeset correctly if they don't appear in the `.map` file?  How does XeTeX know about them?

Comment: @User That happens at a different level: the font knows those ligatures.

Comment: I managed to add another ligature for `gy` by creating a new character in the font and by adding a line in the map file which replaces the combination of `g` and `y` by the ligature `gy`.   This works.  But, what should I have done instead for making the font know about the ligature and so for not needing to modify the `.map` file?

Comment: @User You have to modify the font tables (with fontforge)

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using the "Monotype Baskerville" font, you actually have a choice of two weights for the em-dash symbol: `\char"0214` (the default) and `\char"0215`. The former glyph is indeed extremely thin; the latter is a lot thicker, and it may even be too thick for your taste. Your call.

If you like the latter form, you could set up a macro via an instruction such as

```
    \newcommand\thickemdash{\char"0215}
```

so that you don't have to remember the Unicode character slot of the glyph.

The following MWE runs on my system (MacOSX 10.11.1., MacTeX2015) under both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Baskerville} % Monotype Baskerville

\begin{document}

a---a a\char"2014a a\char"2015a

\end{document}
```