# LuaLaTeX: Change kerning around "1" to simulate proportional figures

Tags: luatex, kerning, opentype, luacode, helvetica

I have the problem that both the original Helvetica and the Neue Helevetica font families by Linotype, in their OpenType versions, seem to not have proportional figures, only tabular figures, where each figure is monospaced. I tried switching to proportional figures with `fontspec` but it doesn't change the appearance a bit.

I need the proportional figures for paragraph text where tabular figures look weird. I find this situation pretty baffling, given that it seems to be a professional and well-known font. The tabular figures are most visible with the "1", which has too much space around it.

I found a possible solution inside LuaLaTeX with this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/323718/75284
but per David Carlisle's comment this approach would break numeric uses in other LaTeX commands. He mentions virtual fonts, how would one define a new virtual font and apply the needed kerning pairs?

**Best would be a solution where one could define both generic kerning (left AND right) and define kerning pairs for fine tuning.**

Please substitute Helvetica with a different font in your system if you don't have it.

```
% -*- program: lualatex  -*- 

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

\setmainfont{HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman}


\begin{document}
\obeylines

11111
88888

10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1.
01 11 21 31 41 51 61 71 81 91 .1

Desired output: 1\kern-.15em{1}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

**edit:** follow-up question ragarding setting up both sides of a character to be kerned in LuaLaTeX: [LuaLaTeX: fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature kerning pairs with unexpected behaviour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/370605/75284)

Comment: I don't think you want to do it via the input buffer callback as you will break numeric uses such a  `\includegraphics[width=10pt]...` you should be able to use luatex's virtual font feature to define a font that has less space around the 1

Comment: @David Carlisle: I rewrite my question because of the mentioned issues with numeric uses in other commands. I didn't foresee that.

Comment: "professional and well-known font" but definitely not for tabular data or any kind of number crunching display. original 11 is pretty balanced.

Comment: @percusse: You find the spaced-out 11 to be balanced? In my view these tabular figures look pretty weird in normal running text, and that's my use case here.

Comment: Your 11 looks cramped if used in any other context. These are paragraph typesetting fonts not tabulating data fonts. You are not doing justice to them by using in these situations https://i.stack.imgur.com/biqQT.png

Comment: Also related https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7282/latexs-need-for-a-helvetica-package-with-full-math-support-for-scientific-grap

Comment: @percusse: I don't get your point. My question is how to adjust kerning *for paragraph text* and you could set the kerning to whatever you want if you find my 11 too cramped. As it is, Helvetica has tabular figures which I don't want to use in paragraph typesetting, the kerning looks wrong to me, too spaced out. Your example shows exactly why I want to make the adjustment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

The code below using Arial rather than Helvetica produces the above.

The OP confirms that the code worked with teh Helvetica variant in the original question if

```
if(string.find(name,'HelveticaNeueLTStd'),
```

is used in place of

```
if(string.find(name,'arial')
```

If you switch `\iffalse` to `\iftrue` to use the modified font loader then you get the output below in which the typesetting of `1` has been changed in a subtle barely noticeable way.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\iffalse

\directlua{
%
orig_define_font=luatexbase.remove_from_callback('define_font','luaotfload.define_font')
%
function x_define_font(name,size,id)
  local thisfont=orig_define_font(name,size,id)
  if(string.find(name,'arial') and type(thisfont)=='table') then
    thisfont.characters[49].width=thisfont.characters[49].width-200000
    thisfont.characters[49].commands = {
      {'right',-100000},
      {'special','pdf: 1 0 0 rg'},
      {'char',49},
      {'special','pdf: 0 g'},
      {'right',-100000},
    }
  end
  return thisfont
end
%
%
luatexbase.add_to_callback('define_font',x_define_font,'my_define_font')
%
}

\fi

\setmainfont{arial}

\begin{document}

abc 111 111 111 X

abc 123 111 222 X

abc 222 444 111 X

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please [indent the Lua code](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaStyleGuide)?  Right now it is rather hard to read.

Comment: @HenriMenke done

Comment: @David Charlisle: Your code gives me an error: `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [max level recursion of virtual fonts=100] \end{document}` when changing it to `\iftrue`.

Comment: ... and when changing it to use Helvetica: `if(string.find(name,'HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman')` it compiles again, but without any change in color or kerning. I have TeX Live 2016.

Comment: hm that's odd it works for me with texlive 2017 pretest. I don't see why you should be getting deeply nested virtual fonts.

Comment: @lblb downvote, really?

Comment: @David Carlisle: I got it working by writing`if(string.find(name,'HelveticaNeueLTStd')`, so making the string less specific (without the `-Roman` part). Maybe include this "rule" in your answer, then I can upvote it again. It would also be very helpful to know the meaning and units of the numbers, they don't follow the usual 0.001 em unit.

Comment: @lblb if  you choose to use a different solution and not vote for this  that's fine, but downvoting an answer that's demonstrably correct as posted (even if it doesn't work for all fonts) is just anti-social. It doesn't actually make any difference I'm rep-capped today anyway but still...

Comment: @David Carlisle: I'm sorry about the downvote, I'm regretting it as your solution is working very well for me now, together with the code by Ulrike Fischer.

Comment: as I say it makes no practical difference and even if it had, I could probably manage with 2 less points, just take a bit longer to pass egreg. it just seems odd given it was several minutes work to work that out, to get lumped with spammers and be downvoted. (you can undownvote if you want:-) anyway glad you got it working, I'll add the helvetica version

Comment: @lblb not sure about the units I think they're sp I just shifted it by eye so didn't actually measure anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59099/discussion-between-lblb-and-david-carlisle).

Answer (score 12):

As you seem to want to adjust the spacing only if more numbers are involved, you could change the kernings between two numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

\directlua
{
 fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature
  {
    name = "ktest",
    type = "kern",
    data =
        {
            ["1"] = { 
                      ["1"] =  -200 ,
                      ["2"] =  -200 
                    },
        },
  }
 }
\setmainfont{Arial}[RawFeature=+ktest]
\setsansfont{Arial} %to show the difference

\begin{document}
1111121212

\sffamily

1111121212

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that's probably a better idea than mine, although the virtual font way presumably allows you to do more if you really need the ones to be red

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: yes, your code is certainly more powerful. But I'm not sure if it scales well. E.g. what happen if you want to make in Times New Roman all A green and in the mono-font the punctuation blue?

Comment: ... the details are left to the reader.

Comment: Would it be possible with this approach to also define kerning around a character generally, so to be applied with each possible partner left and right? That would be ideal.

Comment: I asked on the context list: currently it is not possible to add a "Single adjustment positioning" which would do it, but Hans will add it to the fontloader. It then depends on the luaotfload maintainer when it will be available with lualatex (unless you find a way to add the needed code manually).

Comment: Is there a reference somewhere as to _what_ can be done with `\directlua`, e.g., some API documentation?

Comment: @MattKline luatex has a rather large documentation.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer And where might that be? The reference manual (http://www.luatex.org/svn/trunk/manual/luatex.pdf) describes how to invoke `\directlua` and friends, but doesn't seem to discuss what Lua APIs are provided.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn’t do it by adjusting the kerning, but if what you want are Helvetica-style proportional digits, an alternative approach is to substitute a font that has them, such as TeX Gyre Heros, and set the OpenType options to use them.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\newfontfamily\pronums{TeX Gyre Heros}[Numbers={Lining,Proportional}, Scale=MatchUppercase]

\begin{document}
\fontsize{48}{48}
{\sffamily 111 222 333}

{\pronums 111 222 333}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

If you want them in math mode, too, you can load that font for digits only in `unicode-math`.

Comment: This is almost certainly the best idea (+1) even if it doesn't  involve exposing the black arts of lua font setup:-)

Comment: Huh, looks like I wrote `Numbers=Proportional` when I meant Tabular.