# Add extra kerning before certain punctuation in Babel, but not for the typewriter font

Tags: luatex, babel, punctuation, kerning, typewriter

I want to add extra kerning before exclamation marks, question marks, colons, semicolons, etc. and extra kerning before and after en and em dashes. My current code is based off of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/323718/271299) answer.

The only problem is that it applies globally to all font families, including the typewriter font family, which is not ideal. How can I apply this extra kerning for all font families *except* the typewriter family?

This is my current code so far:

```tex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{luacode, babel, fontspec, url}

\babelprovide[main, import]{english}
\babelfont[english]{tt}{Iosevka Slab}
\babelfont[arabic]{tt}{Amiri Typewriter}

\begin{luacode}
    kval = "\\kern 0.05em"
    function kern_dashes ( s )
        s = string.gsub ( s , "([A-Za-z0-9])%-%-" , "%1"..kval.."--" )
        s = string.gsub ( s , "%-%-([A-Za-z0-9])" , "--"..kval.."%1" )
        s = unicode.utf8.gsub ( s, "([A-Za-z0-9])–" , "%1"..kval.."–" )
        s = unicode.utf8.gsub ( s, "–([A-Za-z0-9])" , "–"..kval.."%1" )
        s = unicode.utf8.gsub ( s, "([A-Za-z0-9])—" , "%1"..kval.."—" )
        s = unicode.utf8.gsub ( s, "—([A-Za-z0-9])" , "—"..kval.."%1" )
        s = unicode.utf8.gsub ( s, "([A-Za-z0-9])([!?:;])" , "%1"..kval.."%2" )
        return s
    end
\end{luacode}
\newcommand{\extrakernOn}{\directlua{
    luatexbase.add_to_callback (
    "process_input_buffer" , kern_dashes , "kern_dashes" )}}
\newcommand{\extrakernOff}{\directlua{
    luatexbase.remove_from_callback (
    "process_input_buffer" , "kern_dashes" )}}
\AtBeginDocument{\extrakernOn} % switch function on by default

% Macro to set the amount of extra kerning
\newcommand\kset[1]{\directlua{kval=\luastring{#1}}}

\begin{document}

Colon:
\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The command `\extrakernOff` turns of the extra kerning. I tried to redefine the `\ttfamily` command with the following code to run that command to disable the kerning.

```tex
\let\oldttfamily\ttfamily
\renewcommand{\ttfamily}{\oldttfamily\extrakernOff}
```

But it resulted in the following error message.

```
Module luatexbase Error: No callback list for `process_input_buffer'
(luatexbase)             on input line 3

stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.lua:110: in upvalue 'module_error
'
    /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.lua:117: in upvalue 'luatexbase_e
rror'
    /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.lua:675: in field 'remove_from_ca
llback'
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
\extrakernOff ..._input_buffer" , "kern_dashes" )}
                                                  
l.3 \@nameuse{bbl@beforestart}
                            
?
```

If I use `\setmonofont` instead of `\babelfont[english]{tt}` and remove `\babelfont[arabic]{tt}`, I will get the result that I expected. But I do not want to do that.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit.** I’ve edited the answer to better reflect what the OP wants. And to fix a slip.

An option with `babel` is with a transform, particularly with `\babelprehyphenation`. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{babel, url}

\babelprovide[main, import]{english}

\babelprehyphenation[label=punc-space]{english}{ [A-Za-z0-9] [!?:;] }
  { {},        % Keep the letter/digit
    { insert, penalty = 10000 },    % Insert a penalty
    { insert, space = .05 0 0, data = 1 }, % And a space
    {}         % Keep the punctuation 
  }

\begin{document}

Colon: \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com}

\disablelocaletransform{punc-space}
Colon: \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com}

\enablelocaletransform{punc-space}
Colon: \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here `space` is a space in em units (taken from the first matched char, which is what `data = 1` means): the first number is the normal value, the second is the `plus` and the third is the `minus` (they are mandatory, but can be set to 0). The penalty prevents a line break.

It also shows how to enable and disable the transform, but you need a recent version of `babel` (>=3.85).

The rest of rules can be defined similarly.

Comment: What would be the correct value for `spacefactor` to ensure a distance of 0.05 em before the punctuation? Also, how would I also make this spacing apply to before and after en and em dashes? Finally, is there a way I can switch it off mid document with a command?

Comment: @Amarakon I’ve edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks, it’s almost perfect. There’s just one thing missing: can you show how to ensure a kerning of 0.05em before and after en and em dashes? Of course, I can just change `[!?:;]` to `[!?:;–—]` and then do another `\babelprehyphenation` but with the order reversed. But that would only apply to the Unicode characters for the dashes, not LaTeX’s ligatures for dashes (`--` and `---`).

Comment: Might it work to re-define `\extrakernon` and `\extrakernoff` (in the original question) so that if firsts test which font is in use, then acts (or does not act) based on that decision?

Comment: @rallg How can I check if the current font family is a typewriter font?

Comment: @Amarakon LaTeX command `\f@family` can reveal information within the text. Needs `\makeatletter`. But if you wish to know whether a particular font is monospaced, given the possibility of kern problems: Search this site for `Lua sidebearings`. That shows Lua code for extracting per-character info, including bounding box. If the bounding box for M and i are the same, probably monospaced. Or, get the `FontForge` program and open the font. Looks at some character widths.

Comment: Some typewriter fonts are not monospaced. I want it to check if the typewriter family (`\ttfamily`) is enabled. Also a problem with my original code is that it finds and replaces only what is directly inputted into the file. If you insert a punctuation mark via a command, it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the microtype package for adding extra kerning.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{microtype}

\newcommand{\applykerning}{%
  \SetExtraKerning
    { encoding = *,      % apply to all font encodings
      family = *,        % apply to all font families except "cmtt"
      series = *,        % apply to all font series
      size = *           % apply to all font sizes
    }
    { ! = {0,.05em}, 
      ? = {0,.05em}, 
      : = {0,.05em}, 
      ; = {0,.05em},
      — = {0,.05em} } % adjust kerning values as needed
}

\newcommand{\resetkerning}{%
  \SetExtraKerning
    { encoding = *,      % apply to all font encodings
      family = *,        % apply to all font families except "cmtt"
      series = *,        % apply to all font series
      size = *           % apply to all font sizes
    }
    { ! = {0,0}, 
      ? = {0,0}, 
      : = {0,0}, 
      ; = {0,0},
      — = {0,0} } % reset kerning values to default
}

\begin{document}

\applykerning
Colon: \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com}

\resetkerning
Colon: \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com}

\applykerning
Colon: \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com}

\texttt{Colon: \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com}}

\end{document}
```